# Select all in datatable with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this code in my application and I can' t select all:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name INSIDERSApp.controller:ReferentCtrl
 * @description
 * # ReferentCtrl
 * Controller of the INSIDERSApp
 */
angular.module('INSIDERSApp')
  .controller('ReferentCtrl', function (INSIDERSServices,$log,$scope,DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $q,$filter) {

      $scope.referents = this;
      $scope.referents.selected = {};

      $scope.referents.selectAll = false;
      $scope.referents.toggleAll = toggleAll;
      $scope.referents.toggleOne = toggleOne;

      var titleHtml = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="referents.selectAll" ng-click="referents.toggleAll(referents.selectAll, referents.selected)">';

      $scope.referents.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder

        .fromFnPromise(function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            INSIDERSServices.referents()
                .success(function(data){
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(data){
                    $log.error("ERROR can't get liste of referents");
                });
            return defer.promise;
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        .withLightColumnFilter({
                    '1' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '2' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '3' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '4' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '5' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '6' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '7' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    },
                    '8' : {
                        type : 'text'
                    }
                })


        .withOption('paging', true)
        .withOption('searching', true)
        .withOption('info', true)
        .withLanguageSource('app/styles/plugins/datatables/json/French.json')
        .withDOM(
                      "<'row'<'col-sm-7'l><'col-sm-5'f>>" +
                      "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                      "<'row'<'col-sm-7'i><'col-sm-5'p>>"     
              )
        ;


      $scope.referents.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle(titleHtml).notSortable().renderWith(function (data, type, full, meta) {
                $scope.referents.selected[full.id] = false;
                return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="referents.selected[' + data.id + ']" ng-click="referents.toggleOne(referents.selected)">';
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nom').withTitle('Nom'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('prenom').withTitle('Prénom'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fonction').withTitle('Fonction'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('profil').withTitle('Profil'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('etat').withTitle('MAJ Liste').renderWith(function(data, type) {
                if(data === true) return "Oui";
                else return "Non";
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateMaj').withTitle('Date de MAJ Liste').renderWith(function(data, type) {
                return $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //date filter
            }),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateRelance').withTitle('Date de relance').renderWith(function(data, type) {
                return $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //date filter
            }),
             DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateNotif').withTitle('Date de Notification').renderWith(function(data, type) {
                    return $filter('date')(data, 'dd/MM/yyyy'); //date filter
                })
        ];

      function toggleAll (selectAll, selectedItems) {
          $log.log("IN toggleAll");
            for (var id in selectedItems) {
                if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                    selectedItems[id] = selectAll;
                }
            }
        }
        function toggleOne (selectedItems) {
            $log.log("IN toggleOne");
            for (var id in selectedItems) {
                if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                    if(!selectedItems[id]) {
                        $scope.referents.selectAll = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            $scope.referents.selectAll = false;
        }  
  });


    <div class="main-container content-active">
    <div class="content">
                <div ng-controller="ReferentCtrl as referents">
    <p class="text-danger">You selected the following rows:</p>
    <p>
        </p><pre>{{ referents.selected |json }}</pre>
    <p></p>

    <table datatable="" dt-options="referents.dtOptions" dt-columns="referents.dtColumns" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered"></table></div> </div>
```

I follow this tutorial:
[enter image description here][1]
http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/rowSelect

Any help please but it doesn't work!!

Answer (score 1):

i find the solution: 
I add 'createdRow' and 'headerCallback' in my code and $compile in my Controller function:

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name INSIDERSApp.controller:ReferentCtrl
 * @description # ReferentCtrl Controller of the INSIDERSApp
 */
angular
  .module('INSIDERSApp')
  .controller(
    'ReferentCtrl',
    function(INSIDERSServices,$compile, $log, $scope, DTOptionsBuilder,
      DTColumnBuilder, $q, $filter) {

     $scope.referents = this;
     $scope.referents.selected = {};

     $scope.referents.selectAll = false;
     $scope.referents.toggleAll = toggleAll;

     $scope.referents.toggleOne = toggleOne;
     
     var titleHtml = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="referents.selectAll" ng-click="referents.toggleAll(referents.selectAll, referents.selected)">';

     $scope.referents.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder

       .fromFnPromise(
         function() {
          var defer = $q.defer();
          INSIDERSServices
            .referents()
            .success(function(data) {
             defer.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(
              function(data) {
               $log
                 .error("ERROR can't get liste of referents");
              });
          return defer.promise;
         })
       .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
       .withLightColumnFilter({
        '1' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '2' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '3' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '4' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '5' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '6' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '7' : {
         type : 'text'
        },
        '8' : {
         type : 'text'
        }
       })

       .withOption('paging', true)
       .withOption('searching', true)
       .withOption('info', true)
       .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
                 $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
             })
             .withOption('headerCallback', function(header) {
                 if (!$scope.referents.headerCompiled) {
                  $scope.referents.headerCompiled = true;
                     $compile(angular.element(header).contents())($scope);
                 }
             }) 
       .withLanguageSource(
         'app/styles/plugins/datatables/json/French.json')
       .withDOM(
         "<'row'<'col-sm-7'l><'col-sm-5'f>>"
           + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>"
           + "<'row'<'col-sm-7'i><'col-sm-5'p>>");

     $scope.referents.dtColumns = [
       DTColumnBuilder
         .newColumn(null)
         .withTitle(titleHtml)
         .notSortable()
         .renderWith(
           function(data, type, full, meta) {
            $scope.referents.selected[full.id] = false;
            return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="referents.selected['
              + data.id
              + ']" ng-click="referents.toggleOne(referents.selected)">';
           }),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('nom').withTitle('Nom'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('prenom').withTitle(
         'Prénom'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('fonction').withTitle(
         'Fonction'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('profil').withTitle(
         'Profil'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('etat').withTitle(
         'MAJ Liste').renderWith(
         function(data, type) {
          if (data === true)
           return "Oui";
          else
           return "Non";
         }),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateMaj').withTitle(
         'Date de MAJ Liste').renderWith(
         function(data, type) {
          return $filter('date')(data,
            'dd/MM/yyyy'); // date filter
         }),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateRelance').withTitle(
         'Date de relance').renderWith(
         function(data, type) {
          return $filter('date')(data,
            'dd/MM/yyyy'); // date filter
         }),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('dateNotif').withTitle(
         'Date de Notification').renderWith(
         function(data, type) {
          return $filter('date')(data,
            'dd/MM/yyyy'); // date filter
         }) ];

     function toggleAll(selectAll, selectedItems) {
      $log.log("IN toggleAll");
      for ( var id in selectedItems) {
       if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        selectedItems[id] = selectAll;
       }
      }
      
      
     }
     function toggleOne(selectedItems) {
      $log.log("IN toggleOne");
      for ( var id in selectedItems) {
       if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        if (!selectedItems[id]) {
         $scope.referents.selectAll = false;
         return;
        }
       }
      }
      $scope.referents.selectAll = true;
     }

    });
```

```html
<div class="main-container content-active">
    <div class="content">
    <div ng-controller="ReferentCtrl as referents">
    <p class="text-danger">You selected the following rows:</p>
    <p>
        </p><pre>{{ referents.selected |json }}</pre>
        
    <p></p>
    
    <table datatable="" dt-options="referents.dtOptions" dt-columns="referents.dtColumns" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer"></table>
                 </div>
                 
                 </div>
        
     </div>
```

Comment: I use this method, But after refresh datatable by `draw()`, it doesn't work! Did you have any idea?